# How to compare data between two tables where one table is in oracle other is in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have two tables with the same table structure. One in oracle and the other in Postgres. I would like to compare the data between the two tables. I cannot use DB_Link, because of some connectivity issues.

I have copied both the contents to an excel sheet.  But still having issues comparing the data.

Please suggest a suitable option to compare the data between the two tables.

Comment: What about using a foreign table in Postgres?

Comment: And what are the "some connectivity issues"?  Forget oracle vs. postgres for the moment. Just think about the logic. How do you expect to compare two things when you cannot communicate between the two things?   Address your "some connectivity issues" You could extract each to a csv file, put the two files on the same server, then run a 'diff' on them. But even that would require that you overcome the "some connectivity problems".

Comment: EdStevens  "some connectivity issues" I mentioned is that  I would not be able to establish DB_LInk  connectivity between oracle and postgres to perform the data comparison. I will try to extract the data from both the tables in csv format and try to run a diff.

Comment: I was suggesting that perhaps we address the connection issues. You still have to have the network connectivity to get both csv files to a common machine.